# Run eclipse on windows 7 64 bit

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to run eclipse for java in Windows 7 64bit edition, and when I run the eclipse.exe file, absolutely nothing happens. A ephimeral javaw.exe process is created in the task manager, but as I said, it's just there for a split second, and it disappears, after that NOTHING. I tried compiling a small program with the javac.exe file, and that works all right, but for some reason I cannot run Eclipse.

Any suggestions on what I could be doing wrong. I'm a complete Java noob, it's the first time I try to do this.

These are the files I have, and I downloaded the Windows 64bit version of eclipse.

[image]

Thanks!

**EDIT**

OK, solved. The book I'm using is misleading... it said I should use the javaw.exe file from jdk1.6.0_21, and doing that didn't work. Now I tried with one in jre6, and it ran.

Thanks everyone and sorry for the hassle!

Comment: Can you try running eclipse.exe from a command prompt and see if it produces any output.

Comment: It is working on that platform for me.  Check the Windows application event log, too.

Comment: no output whatsoever... http://img838.imageshack.us/img838/1000/cmd.png

Comment: Make sure you have the right Eclipse version http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.5.1-200909170800/eclipse-SDK-3.5.1-win32-x86_64.zip

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, check you `eclipse.ini` (even a space at the end of a line can prevent eclipse from starting)

Second I am surprised to see java* file in your Eclipse distribution.
You shouldn't' have those, and instead refer to the right java (64 bits) in your `eclipse.ini`.

In both case, see this [**`eclipse.ini`** as a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/3275659#3275659).

Check also the `<workspace>/.metadata/.log` (error log file).

---

> I just added it there because it was asking for it, supposedly the best way it to put it in the PATH.

If eclipse is "asking for it", that means your current java installation is not part of the `PATH`. It need to be reference from the `eclipse.ini` file.
See also **[FAQ How do I run Eclipse?](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse%3F)**

---

In any event, **don't copy any java files around**.
Used in your `eclipse.ini` a path like:

```
-vm
C:/Prog/Java/jdk1.6.0_21/jre/bin/server/jvm.dll
```

Comment: I just added it there because it was asking for it, supposedly the best way it to put it in the PATH. I'm checking the eclipse.ini now.

Comment: eclipse.ini had a line break at the end, removed it, and no luck, still does absolutely nothing.

Comment: Omg all of that? Why can't these things be like visual studio, just install and that's it...

Comment: @Carlo: don't add java in your eclipse installation. Reference it through your eclipse.ini.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm too noob. Which line references it?

Comment: @Carlo: just added the link to the Eclipse FAQ. As Jamie mentions, make sure to have a JDK 64bits installed

Comment: @Carlo: as mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/3275659#3275659, the **`-vm`** part reference the jdk path, as in `-vm
C:/Prog/Java/jdk1.6.0_21/jre/bin/server/jvm.dll` (over two separate lines in the eclipse.ini).

Comment: Fixed it, please see edit. It was something stupid, book mislead me. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your answer was the more complete one, so I marked it as the correct one. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the 64-bit version of Java? http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_win64bit.xml

Comment: I believe yes. Is there an accurate way to confirm?

Comment: @Carlo: Look where Java is installed. If it's in `\Program Files`, then it's 64-bit, if it's in `\Program Files (x86)` it's the 32-bit version. Your Eclipse version has to match the bitness of the Java version.

Comment: You aren't supposed to copy around `java` or `javaw` anyway. Leave them where they are.

Comment: Fixed it, please see edit. It was something stupid, book mislead me. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced relatively little trouble moving to 64-bit java:

1. Download Eclipse Helios 64-bit version
2. Download Java 6 SDK 64-bit version
3. Install both
4. Run

The issues may arise if you have both 32-bit and 64-bit JDKs in the same machine. If you want to explicitly run Eclipse with one JVM, then you need to specify its full path in eclipse.ini.

e.g.

-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_20/bin/javaw.exe

Where the path points to the 64-bit version.

The other issue I encountered after moving is that the Subclipse plugin by default uses a 32-bit DLL backend and therefore doesn't work. However Subclipse also works with a pure-Java back-end for Eclipse called JavaHL which solved that issue.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem and did not know how to proceed.

I did following things to resolve it.

1. In eclipse.ini enter the vm argument to which jre you want to use
   -vm
   C:\Java\jdk1.7\jre\bin\javaw.exe
2. If you have -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7 line in your eclipse 
   make sure that version is matching the one that is mentione in step 1.
   ( in my case it was 1.6 and I had to change this value to 1.7)
3. Launch eclipse.exe from the command line